# Retrieve Image from folder based on stored path From database

Tags: jquery, image

I want to display image from folder in list by jquery and i am using mvc 4.0. image pathe is retroves by stored procedure .

Answer (score 0):

```
// MVC action which returns a list of paths as Json array
public ActionResult GetImages()
{
    IEnumerable<string> imagePaths = GetImagePathsFromStoredProcedure();
    return Json(imagePaths, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

function getImagePathds() {
    $.get("/Home/GetImages", function (data, status) {
        if (status === "success") {
            for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
                var imagePath = data[i];
                $("<img alt='' />").attr("src", imagePath).appendTo($("body"));
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: what i have to write in view ??